# Amazon RDS: How many Oracle instances/databases

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a couple of questions on AWS RDS service for migrating an oracle 19c server on RHEL with 3 standalone instances and databases:

1. Can RDS instance support multiple oracle standalone instances/databases or only one instance?
2. If I have an existing RDS service running in AWS, can I migrate another on-premise oracle database to the RDS database as another oracle schema?

Have not tried it yet.

Answer (score 1):

1. RDS for Oracle limits one instance to a single database. However you can have multiple schemas in one database.
2. An account can have up to 40 BYOL type Oracle RDS instances, or up to 10 instances where license is included. You can also increase these limits by contacting AWS support.

See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.DBInstance.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

1. Each RDS instance equals one database. However, you can set up multiple RDS instances, if you want to.
2. For migrations, please have a look at the [Database Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/) (DMS). Regarding your schema in particular, please check the [Schema Conversion Tool](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/schema-conversion-tool/) which is a part of the DMS.

Sorry I can’t be more specific as the questions are rather vague themselves.